# How do I prevent array copies from editing the original?

Tags: javascript, arrays, copy

```js
    var level1screen = [
     ["B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B"],
     ["B", "A", "A", "A", "A", "D", "C", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B"],
     ["B", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B"],
     ["B", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B"],
     ["B", "A", "B", "B", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "A", "B"],
     ["B", "E", "D", "D", "A", "A", "A", "A", "D", "D", "A", "B"],
     ["B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B"]
    ];
    
    var screen = [
     ["B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B"],
     ["B", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "A", "C", "C", "A", "C", "B"],
     ["B", "C", "A", "A", "A", "C", "C", "A", "C", "C", "A", "B"],
     ["B", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "A", "A", "C", "A", "A", "B"],
     ["B", "C", "A", "A", "A", "C", "A", "A", "C", "A", "A", "B"],
     ["B", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "A", "A", "C", "A", "A", "B"],
     ["B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B"]
    ];
    
    var selectedScreen = screen;
    
    var player = {
     posX: 0,
     posY: 0,
     speed: 0,
     maxSpeed: 5,
     movementTime: 0,
     jump: 0,
     maxJump: 3,
     health: 100,
     coins: 0,
     maxCoins: 1,
     movement: true
    };
    
    var textures = {
     A: "skyblue",
     B: "firebrick",
     C: "gold",
     D: "black",
     E: "green",
     P: "white"
    };
    
    function ready(screen){
     var start = [];
     for(i in screen){
      if(screen[i].includes("E")){
       start[0] = screen[i].indexOf("E");
       start[1] = parseInt(i);
      }
     }
     if(start.length == 0){
      alert("Bad level layout");
      throw "Bad level layout";
     }
     player.posX = start[0];
     player.posY = start[1];
     screen[player.posY][player.posX] = "P";
    }
    
    function updateScreen(screen, pixelWidth, pixelHeight){
     var canvas = document.getElementById("screen");
     context = canvas.getContext("2d");
     canvas.width = screen[0].length * pixelWidth;
     canvas.height = screen.length * pixelHeight;
     context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
     var x = 0;
     var y = 0;
     for(i in screen){
      for(j in screen[i]){
       var colour = textures[screen[i][j]];
       context.fillStyle = colour;
       context.fillRect(x, y, 100, 100);
       x += pixelWidth;
      }
      x = 0;
      y += pixelHeight;
     }
     if(!player.movement){
      context.font = "32px Arial";
      context.fillText("Paused. P to resume.", 450, 350);
      context.textAlign="center"; 
     }
    }
    
    document.onkeydown = function(event){
     event = event || window.event;
     if(player.movement && (event.keyCode == 87 || event.keyCode == 38 || event.keyCode == 32)){
      event.preventDefault();
      console.log(selectedScreen[player.posY][player.posX]);
      screen[player.posY][player.posX] = selectedScreen[player.posY][player.posX];
      if(screen[player.posY - 1] != "B"){
       player.posY -= 1;
       alert("JUMP");
      }
     } else if(player.movement && (event.keyCode == 83 || event.keyCode == 40)){
      event.preventDefault();
      screen[player.posY][player.posX] = selectedScreen[player.posY][player.posX];
      if(screen[player.posY + 1] != "B"){
       player.posY += 1;
       alert("DUCK");
      }
     } else if(player.movement && (event.keyCode == 65 || event.keyCode == 37)){
      event.preventDefault();
      screen[player.posY][player.posX] = selectedScreen[player.posY][player.posX];
      if(screen[player.posX - 1] != "B"){
       player.posX -= 1;
       alert("LEFT");
      }
     } else if(player.movement && (event.keyCode == 68 || event.keyCode == 39)){
      event.preventDefault();
      screen[player.posY][player.posX] = selectedScreen[player.posY][player.posX];
      if(screen[player.posX + 1] != "B"){
       player.posX += 1;
       alert("RIGHT");
      }
     } else if(event.keyCode == 80){
      player.movement = !player.movement;
     }
     screen[player.posY][player.posX] = "P";
     console.log(event.keyCode);
     updateScreen(screen, 100, 100);
    }
    
    screen = level1screen;
    selectedScreen = level1screen;
    updateScreen(screen, 100, 100);
    ready(screen);
```

```html
<canvas id="screen">HTML5 Canvas is not supported by your browser.</canvas>
```

When I try playing, the player (white patch) fills up the whole screen and does not remain as one dot. I checked and realised that level1screen, screen, and selectedScreen all were the same. I think the source of this problem is that level1screen and selectedScreen are being edited when they should not be. Could this be a problem that the arrays are passed by reference?

Comment: Yes.  Try something like `var array2 = array1.slice();`

Answer (score 0):

You have through your code: `var selectedScreen = screen;`, `screen = level1screen;`, and `selectedScreen = level1screen;`. As you say, arrays are passed by reference so they all end up being level1screen. If you want to copy those arrays and have them remain separate then you have to create a new array. This can be with the spread operation, `var selectedScreen = [...screen]` or with slice as mentioned in a comment, `var selectedScreen = screen.slice(0)`. You will then also need to declare new arrays down the bottom again in the same way, rather than the existing `screen =` and `selectedScreen =` as I mentioned above.